# mplfinance freezes IPython console

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to create a candlestick plot using mplfinance but whenever I run mplfinance.plot() the IPython console in Spyder freezes like it's working on something but it never finishes running nor does it respond to ^C.

```
import ta
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf

naftrac = yf.Ticker("NAFTRACISHRS.MX")

# get historical market data
hist = naftrac.history(period = "1y", interval = "1wk", actions = False)
hist = hist.dropna()

mpf.plot(hist, type = "candle", volume = True)
```

I'm using the standard 3.7.4 python anaconda install, with pandas 1.0.3, matplotlib 3.2.1, and IPython 7.8.0. My mplfinance version is 0.12.4a0.

Anyone else faced the same issue? How do you fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue and would be interested in how to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that is expected to be fixed by the end of this week.  In the meantime, you can override the bug by including kwarg `block=False`:

```
mpf.plot(hist, type = "candle", volume = True, block=False)
```